# AForge.net Crop Car Photo

Tags: object, shapes, detection, aforge

I have just started using AForge.net and would like to know if there is a way to crop an photo containing a car to remove most of the background and leave only the car.

The car photo would be taken using a mobile device, which means that it could be any type of car, colour, background.

I have tried a few things including using blob count to try and detect car shape, however this only detects the wheels.

I need the solution to be c# and be capable of running on mono (xamarin).

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

[I have attached a photo, illustrating input and expected image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siVfr.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

the key here is to get the car color by searching for the dominating color in the middle of the picture (assuming that the car body paint will be their) make a copy for processing then try HSL filtering for the found color which will keep only the car color and remove the background
[AForge HSL Filtering](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/743311a9-6c27-972d-39d2-ddc383dd1dd4.htm) 
after that grayscale > blob search and get the biggest blob rectangle then crop that rectangle from the original image ,, DONE! :)

i would support you with some code if you want to